# How to get array from many-to-many relationship in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have users that can manage multiple clusters and each cluster has multiple countries belonging to it.
I got the auth user clusters using:

```
$userClusters = Auth::user()->clusters()->lists('name','cluster_id');
```

now i need to get countries for each cluster (i have one to many relationship between clusters and countries)

**Countries Relationship**

```
public function countries()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Country');
}
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? Can you also show the methods for your eloquent relationships?

Comment: i'm using 5.2
relationship in cluster model:
public function countries()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Country');
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
$clusters = Auth::user()->load('clusters.countries')->clusters;
```

The `load()` method will return the original model so you access the cluster relationship straight away.

Comment: i'm new to laravel, so can you tell me how to print this out with dd(); for example to get the cluster name and the countries inside each cluster ?

Comment: @AhmedHammam As in an array where the keys are the cluster names and the values are the collections of countries?

Comment: it seems that your code is working great :)
i have used dd($clusters[0]->countries); to check the countries for the 1st cluster for ex.

Comment: Glad I could help. If I've understood your previous comment you could do something like `dd($cluster->keyBy('name')->map(function ($item) { return $item->countries;}));`

Answer (score 2):

try it

```
 $userClusters = Auth::user()->clusters
 $userClusters->load('countries')
```

and read it is

[laravel eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)

Comment: how can i load the output of $userClusters->load('countries') into dd();

Comment: at the end write   ->toArray() or collect($model)->toArray();  
try it

 $userClusters = Auth::user()->clusters
 $userClusters->load('countries')
and read it is [laravel collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections)

Answer (score 0):

```
$userClusters = User::with('clusters.countries')->where('id',Auth::id())->get();
```

Comment: i got this error: Call to a member function countries() on string